# Google Analytics Campaigns - cleanup URL after arriving to webpage?

Tags: google-analytics, url-rewriting, url-parameters

After visitor lands to my webpage using campaign url:

```
http://www.mydomain.com?utm_source=signature&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=myname
```

Is it possible to do a rewrite to `http://www.mydomain.com` to cleanup the URL in the address bar?

Will it still preserve the campaign data if I do a simple mod_rewrite redirect?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_source
RewriteRule .* http://www.mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Or how else can I cleanup the URL?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible by using server side redirection AND by following the instructions on this Google reference page:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking

Please note that the _setCamp... functions must be called before this code:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you redirect, it will not preserve that information.   You could store this information in a cookie before redirecting and then read it from a cookie.   I worked with a website that did that for URL canonicalization.  It works, but it is a pain to implement and some data gets lost or truncated.

Comment: OK, so how do I transfer the data from PHP variable (cookie) to Google Analytics Campaigns?

Comment: I guess that won't work.  I've logged cookies for my own analytics, but never sent them to Google Analytics.